# Angular 2 - View not updated with route observable

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, observable

My view model does not seem to be updating using the route params observable.

My Component looks like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { RSSService} from '../rss.service';
import { RegionService } from '../region.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: '[rss-list]',
  templateUrl: './rss.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rss.component.css'],
  providers: [RSSService]
})
export class RssComponent  implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private _region: Object;
  subscription;

  @Input() rssItems: any[];

  constructor( 
    private region: RegionService, 
    private rss: RSSService, 
    private _route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private _router: Router
    ) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this._region = this.region.getRegion(params["region"]);
      this.rssItems = this.rss.getRss(this._region);
      this.rssItems.forEach((item)=> item.checked = false);
      console.log ('rss model',this.rssItems); // model is updating here
    })

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log ('Destroy', this._route);
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And my view:

```js
<tr *ngFor="let item of rssItems" >
<td><input type="checkbox" [disabled]="item.deleted" ([ngModel])="item.checked"></td>
<td>
    <div [class.deleted]="item.deleted">{{item.title}}</div>
    <div [class.deleted]="item.deleted"><a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.url}} </a></div>
</td>
<td>
    <i (click)="rssDelete(item)" *ngIf="!item.deleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <i (click)="rssEdit(item)" *ngIf="!item.deleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
    <i (click)="rssUndelete(item)" *ngIf=" item.deleted " class="glyphicon glyphicon-modal-window "></i>
</td>
</tr>
```

The console.log shows the rssItems model is being updated but the view never changes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is all a little new to me.

Thanks.

Comment: try using <tr *ngFor="let item of rssItems | async" >

Comment: read this for detail http://briantroncone.com/?p=623

Comment: Nope.  Getting following: Error in ./RssComponent class RssComponent - inline template:0:4 caused by: Invalid argument  '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: do this in component

 this.subscription = this._route.params.subscribe(res => {
 this.rssItems = res
 });

then do this in HTML file like this

<tr *ngFor="let item of rssItems | async" >

follow the link i mentioned above

Comment: Try to print rssitems out of the table...

{{rssitems | json}}

{{rssitems | json}} show the newVal or oldVal ?

Comment: Values stay the same

Comment: can you reproduce this in a plunker, or at least show the component code and html whici is rendering the rss-list ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see ngOnChanges rssitems is an @Input so every change ngOnChanges should have been call:

```
class YouComponent implements OnChanges{
  ngOnChanges (changes){
    //whats up?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rssItems must be an Observable in order to use `| async`